# I need to write a VBA loop that finds a non-blank cell, then selects specific cells in that row to copy to another sheet

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I will start off by saying I am very new to VBA in Excel and am self taught.
I have a spreadsheet for recording training hours on.  I'm trying to write a code that looks for a non-blank cell in 3 columns that are "A", "B" or "A & B".  Once the code has found the non blank column, I want it to then select a specific range (say, A1:C1 & D1 & F1:J1) but on the row of the non blank cell, it then needs to copy these values to either sheet A, sheet B or both sheets A and B, based on which column has a value.  I want it to paste to the next none blank row on these sheets (after clearing the sheet so I don't end up with duplicates) to a range of say A1:F1 (sorry these ranges are estimates atm).
I then need this code to loop through every row that isn't completely blank from the first sheets.

I have tried various things and have managed to get small elements of it to work individually, but am struggling to get the loop working to the next non-blank cell in the column and how to tell it to select a different range depending on which column it finds a value (number of hours)

So far I have tried:

```
'Sub Macro1()
''    Dim r1, r2, r3, myMultipleRange As Range
''    Set r1 = Sheets("Record").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2))
''    Set r2 = Sheets("Record").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))
''    Set r3 = Sheets("Record").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5))
''    Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2, r3)
'    Sheets("Record").Select
'    Range("D4:D6").Select
'    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
'    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)).Select
''    myMultipleRange.Select
'End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    Dim r1, r2, r3, myMultipleRange As Range
    Set r1 = Sheets("Record").Range("A4:b4")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Record").Range("D4")
    Set r3 = Sheets("Record").Range("F4:I4")
    Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2, r3)
    myMultipleRange.Select

End Sub
```

I want the first sheet to be split out into the relevant other sheets so the totals can be extracted and all other information on that row

This is the input tab "Record"
[Input tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI49Q.png)

And this is one of the two output tabs "CPD" (the other is "Off the job training")

[Output tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coi96.png)

Edit: I've got slightly further with this now.  Rather than trying to select the entire range at once, I'm trying to copy each part separately.  If I comment I'm not sure how I'm going to be able to loop this to run through all the rows and the three columns that are the variables though, any thoughts?

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("CPD").Select
    Range("H7:N1449").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("Record").Select
    Range("D4:D6").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CPD").Select
    Range("H3:K3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Record").Select
        Range("D4:D6").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("CPD").Select
        Range("H3:K3").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 2).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Record").Select
            Range("D4:D6").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("CPD").Select
            Range("H3:K3").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58065944/edit) and add what you tried ?

Comment: This is as far as I've got with it so far.  The first one didn't work, so I started trying the second.  I'm trying to tackle the selection problem first, then it'll be the copy paste, and finally the loop for the 3 columns

Comment: Can you also please add a screenshot of your excel file and of the output excepted so I can visualise what yuo are asking for

Comment: The range of the output tab starts at column H purely because I currently have it doing this manually through formulas, but it is very slow using this method.  I'd rather have it start from column A using a macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to after a bit of trial and error, I think I have managed to come up with a working solution.  Feel free to check my code though!

```
Sub Calculate()
    Dim x As Long
        Sheets("CPD").Select
        Range("H7:N1449").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Sheets("Off the job training").Select
        Range("H7:N1449").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
            For x = 1 To 50
            Sheets("Record").Select
            Range("C7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                    Range("D7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                            Range("E7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                                If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                                    Exit For
                                Else
                                    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)).Select
                                    Selection.Copy
                                    Sheets("CPD").Select
                                    Range("H500").Select
                                    Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                                    Sheets("Off the job training").Select
                                    Range("H500").Select
                                    Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                                        Sheets("Record").Select
                                        Range("E7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                                        Selection.Copy
                                        Sheets("CPD").Select
                                        Range("H500").Select
                                        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Select
                                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                                        Sheets("Off the job training").Select
                                        Range("H500").Select
                                        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Select
                                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                                            Sheets("Record").Select
                                            Range("E7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                                            Range(ActiveCell(1, 2), ActiveCell(1, 5)).Select
                                            Selection.Copy
                                            Sheets("CPD").Select
                                            Range("H500").Select
                                            Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Select
                                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                                            Sheets("Off the job training").Select
                                            Range("H500").Select
                                            Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Select
                                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                                End If
                        Else
                            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            Sheets("Off the job training").Select
                            Range("H500").Select
                            Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                                Sheets("Record").Select
                                Range("D7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                                Selection.Copy
                                Sheets("Off the job training").Select
                                Range("H500").Select
                                Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Select
                                ActiveSheet.Paste
                                    Sheets("Record").Select
                                    Range("D7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                                    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)).Select
                                    Selection.Copy
                                    Sheets("Off the job training").Select
                                    Range("H500").Select
                                    Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Select
                                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                        End If
                Else
                    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("CPD").Select
                    Range("H500").Select
                    Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                        Sheets("Record").Select
                        Range("C7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                        Selection.Copy
                        Sheets("CPD").Select
                        Range("H500").Select
                        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                            Sheets("Record").Select
                            Range("C7").Offset(x - 1, 0).Select
                            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6)).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            Sheets("CPD").Select
                            Range("H500").Select
                            Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                End If
            Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Would be better if you avoid select

Comment: What should I use instead? Or do I just do the copy/paste instead?